# Вывести из базы mysqli строки в переменную

Tags: php, mysqli

Основная страница layout.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.php">Index</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="content"><?php echo $content; ?></div>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('a').click(function() {
                    var url = $(this).attr('href');

                    $.ajax({
                        url:     url + '?ajax=1',
                        success: function(data){
                            $('#content').html(data);
                        }
                    });

                    if(url != window.location){
                        window.history.pushState(null, null, url);
                    }

                    return false;
                });

                $(window).bind('popstate', function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        url:     location.pathname + '?ajax=1',
                        success: function(data) {
                            $('#content').html(data);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Страница index.php а точнее это $content

```
include("dbconfig.php");

$query=mysqli_query($dbconfig,"select * from table");

if (isset($_GET['ajax'])) {
while($var=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
    echo $content="<li>".$var['title'].'</li>';
}
} else {
    include_once 'layout.php';
}
```

Если использовать это в index.php всё работает! Но здесь без вывода из бд.

```
$content = '123321test123321';
if (isset($_GET['ajax'])) {
    echo $content;
} else {
    include_once 'layout.php';
}
```

Попробовал так и тоже не получилось:

```
include("dbconfig.php");
$query=mysqli_query($dbconfig,"select * from table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if ((isset($_GET['ajax'])) && ($count >= 1)) {
    echo $content="<li>".$row['title']."</li>";
} else {
    include_once 'layout.php';
}
```

самое интересное, если я нажму по ссылке, то всё прекрасно выводит!

Comment: Ваш вопрос скорее не о History API, а о ajax. Опишите, в чем именно проблема ваше второго блока кода.

Comment: Вот [демо](http://plutov.by/demo/history-api1) но тут вывод не из базы данных а напрямую из файла!

Comment: Без вашего кода, в котором ваши ссылки на пагинацию и ajax-запросы, пока тяжело что-то сказать.

Comment: Я тут ещё информацию добавил, чтоб более понятно было.

Comment: У вас сслыки `?id=1`, а вы им еще `+'?ajax=1'` делаете, что в сумме убивает ваш параметр `ajax`

Comment: А как тогда правильно исправить на ?id=* если id берётся из mysqli?

Comment: Если в url уже есть `?`, то следующий параметр надо добавлять через `&`.  Попробуйте такой код `url: url + (/\?/.test(url) ? '&':'?') + 'ajax=1'`

Comment: у меня получается вот такая ссылка http://127.0.0.1/demo/?id=* но теперь страница обновляется, если использовать как было страница не обновляется, кстати забыл сказать, что ругается на это строчку 
<div id="content"><?php echo $content; ?></div> Notice: Undefined variable: content in layout.php on line 72 из за этого не выводит из бд

Comment: В последнем if-else в index.php вы подключаете layout.php в `else`, но $content у вас задана в `if`

Comment: а как сделать что типо таково?                                                     $content=
if (isset($_GET['ajax'])) {
while($var=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
 echo "<li>".$var['title'].'</li>';
}
} else {
    include_once 'layout.php';
};

Comment: Что должно быть в $content, если страничку запрашиваем без аякса?

Comment: Давай начнём с простого, я изменил немного вопрос, так больше будет понятней

Comment: Подключиться к bd для начала, сделать запрос к таблице сделать выборку (все строки или конкретную строку может последнюю) получим массив из массива уже вставлять)

Comment: Добавьте в ваш ответ больше конкретной информации. Например ваш код.

Comment: Будьте добры, помогите мне в этом. К базе подключён, выборка есть, данные выводит, только если щёлкать по ссылке Index.php, а при обновлении выдаёт ошибку: Notice: Undefined variable: content in layout.php on line 17

Comment: <div id="content"><?php echo $content; ?></div> в этой строчке у вас ошибка. программа на этой строке ещё не знает что это за переменная $content - где вы её объявили? программа читает файл сверху вниз. сверху никакого подключённого файла где объявляется эта переменная нету, вот он и ругается

Comment: Но как то же работает на таком примере если index.php будет без вывода из базы!                                        $content = '1234567890qwertyuiioop0987654321';
if (isset($_GET['ajax'])) {
    echo $content;
} else {
    include_once 'layout.php';
}

Comment: в layaut.php
include 'index.php';
проверь!

Comment: Он там не должен быть!

Comment: Тут скорее проблема в скрипте наверно, а именно виновата вот эта строчка: if (isset($_GET['ajax']))

Comment: за это отвечает  <div id="content"><?php echo $content; ?></div> который прекрасно работает с обычным выводом, что писал в вопросе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**layout.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php">Index</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="content"><?php echo $content; ?></div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('a').click(function() {
                var url = $(this).attr('href');

                $.ajax({
                    // url уже может содержать параметры, так что проверяем,
                    // как нам добавлять ещё один параметр
                    url: url + (/\?/.test(url) ? '&':'?') + 'ajax=1',
                    success: function(data){
                        $('#content').html(data);
                    }
                });

                if(url != window.location){
                    window.history.pushState(null, null, url);
                }

                return false;
            });

            $(window).bind('popstate', function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: location.pathname + (/\?/.test(location.pathname) ? '&':'?') + 'ajax=1',
                    success: function(data) {
                        $('#content').html(data);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.php**

```
include("dbconfig.php");
$limit = 3;
$start = 0;
$content = '';
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = intval($_GET['id']);
    $start = ($id-1) * $limit;
}
//* получаем данные и кладем их в $content
$query = mysqli_query($dbconfig, "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $start, $limit");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $content .= "<li>".$row['title']."</li>";
}
if(isset($_GET['ajax'])) {
    //* если запрос яаксом - возвращаем только данные
    echo $content;
} else {
    //* если обычный запрос - возвращаем всю HTML-страницу
    include_once 'layout.php';
}
```

Comment: А как сделать так уже чтобы вывести в content 2 типа записей?     `$content .= 
 "<li>".$row['title']."</li>"
 "<p>".$row['description']."</p>";`

Comment: А во сам уже понял   `$content .= "<li>".$row['title']."</li>";
 $content .= "<p>".$row['description']."</p>";` если есть лучше вариант обязательно напиши.

Comment: Если будет возможность, ответь на этот [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/656023/dynamic-php-pagination-ajax).